# How can I positioned my p-sidebar primeng below overlay-mask?

Tags: angular

I have a project in angular with a p-sidebar primeng... but when I'll resize my window for the responsive, the sidebar is positioned under the overlay mask.
What can I do? Is there any atribute in primeng to change the position?

(mobile view)
[image]

(screen view)
[image]